# Objective C dismissViewControllerAnimated move last view down

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have two ViewController

VC1 adding VC2 as an subview to itselfe.

VC2 has a `UIButton`, which is calling the follow Code:

```
if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailer setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"BlaBla."]];

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"blabla@gmail.com", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Testtext1"];
    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];      

}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Fehler" message:@"Ihr Gerät unterstützt die gewünschte Funktion nicht" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

After the Mail is done it calls the following:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
    { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hinweis"
                                                      message:@"Vorgang abgebrochen, es wurde keine E-Mail versendet."
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];

    }

        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
    { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hinweis"
                                                      message:@"Ihre E-Mail wurde gespeichert."
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];

    }

        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
    { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hinweis"
                                                      message:@"Ihre E-Mail wird versendet."
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];

    }

        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
    { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hinweis"
                                                      message:@"Vorgang abgebrochen, die E-Mail konnte nicht gesendet werden."
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];
    }

        break;
    default:
    { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hinweis"
                                                      message:@"E-Mail wurde nicht gesendet."
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                            otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];

    }

        break;
}
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}
```

All works fine, but all UIButtons etc in VC2 are now moved, I guess, 20 pixels down.

I cant Imagin why, I guess the problem is I adding a ViewController as Subview to an other ViewController and calling there the methode. But I cant imagin how to solve the issue.

Comment: Are all the buttons moved before or after the dismissal of the mail compose view controller? How do you add VC2 as a subview to VC1? Can you post your code? You might need to set the frame of VC2 to be equal to the bounds of VC1.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem but parent view was moved 20 px up.

Solution was based on changing "Wants full screen". I had to set this values to YES but not to all child view controllers.